# Producer-consumer scenario causing std::system_error on unique_lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, producer-consumer

The following program should create a `JobScheduler` that puts `Job`s into a `running_queue` from a `waiting_queue`. When the `running_queue` is not empty, 2 or more threads execute the `Job` going to sleep for a time specified into it, if the `Job` is completed (`duration == execution_time`) then it is put into the `completed_queue` else it is put into the `running_queue` again, till both `running_queue` and `waiting_queue` are empty.

The `runningLock.unlock()` call will at some point cause a

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'`

Isn't the `runningLock` acquired only from one thread at once? It looks like `.unlock()` has been called even if the thread did not acquire the lock.

`main.cpp`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
// #include "JobScheduler.h"

class Job {

private:
    int id;
    int duration;
    int execution_time;
    int start_time;
    int wait_time;
    float completion_time;

public:
    Job();

    Job(int id, int startTime, int duration);

    Job(const Job &);

    Job& operator=(const Job &);

    ~Job();

    int getId() const;

    void setId(int id);

    int getDuration() const;

    void setDuration(int duration);

    int getExecutionTime() const;

    void setExecutionTime(int executionTime);

    int getStartTime() const;

    void setStartTime(int startTime);

    int getWaitTime() const;

    void setWaitTime(int waitTime);

    int getCompletionTime() const;

    void setCompletionTime(int completionTime);

    bool operator< (const Job&) const;
};

int Job::getId() const {
    return id;
}

void Job::setId(int id) {
    Job::id = id;
}

int Job::getDuration() const {
    return duration;
}

void Job::setDuration(int duration) {
    Job::duration = duration;
}

int Job::getExecutionTime() const {
    return execution_time;
}

void Job::setExecutionTime(int executionTime) {
    execution_time = executionTime;
}

int Job::getStartTime() const {
    return start_time;
}

void Job::setStartTime(int startTime) {
    start_time = startTime;
}

int Job::getWaitTime() const {
    return wait_time;
}

void Job::setWaitTime(int waitTime) {
    wait_time = waitTime;
}

int Job::getCompletionTime() const {
    return completion_time;
}

void Job::setCompletionTime(int completionTime) {
    completion_time = completionTime;
}

Job::Job() : id(0), start_time(0), duration(0) {}

Job::Job(int id, int startTime, int duration) : id(id), start_time(startTime), duration(duration), execution_time(0), wait_time(0), completion_time(0) {}

Job::Job(const Job &job) {
    id = job.id;
    duration = job.duration;
    execution_time = job.execution_time;
    start_time = job.start_time;
    wait_time = job.wait_time;
    completion_time = job.completion_time;
}

Job &Job::operator=(const Job &job) {
    if (this != &job) {
        id = job.id;
        duration = job.duration;
        execution_time = job.execution_time;
        start_time = job.start_time;
        wait_time = job.wait_time;
        completion_time = job.completion_time;
    }

    return *this;
}

bool Job::operator<(const Job &job) const {
    return start_time > job.start_time;
}

Job::~Job() {}

class JobScheduler {
private:
    const int quantum; // ms

    std::vector<std::thread> threadPool;

    std::priority_queue<Job> waitingJobsQueue;

    std::queue<Job> runningJobsQueue;
    std::mutex r_mutex;

    std::vector<Job> completedJobsQueue;
    std::mutex c_mutex;

    std::condition_variable is_empty;
    std::condition_variable is_completed;

    bool done;
public:
    JobScheduler();

    void submit(Job j);
    void start();

    ~JobScheduler();
};

JobScheduler::JobScheduler() : quantum(3000), waitingJobsQueue(), runningJobsQueue(), completedJobsQueue(), done(false) {}

void JobScheduler::submit(Job j) {
    waitingJobsQueue.push(j);
}

void JobScheduler::start() {

    auto startTime = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    for (int i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++) {
        threadPool.emplace_back([this, startTime](){
            std::stringstream msg;
            msg << "thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " created" << std::endl;
            std::cout << msg.str();

            std::unique_lock runningLock(r_mutex);
            while (!done) {
                auto woke_up_time = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
                is_empty.wait(runningLock, [this]{return (!runningJobsQueue.empty() || waitingJobsQueue.empty());});
                auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - woke_up_time);
                int waiting_time = elapsed_time.count();

                if (!runningJobsQueue.empty()) {
                    Job job = runningJobsQueue.front();
                    runningJobsQueue.pop();
                    runningLock.unlock();

                    job.setWaitTime(job.getWaitTime() + waiting_time);

                    float sleep_time = std::min(job.getDuration() - job.getExecutionTime(), quantum);
                    job.setExecutionTime(job.getExecutionTime() + sleep_time);
                    std::stringstream msg1;
                    msg1 << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] running job " << job.getId() << " at t = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime).count() << std::endl;
                    std::cout << msg1.str();
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(static_cast<long>(sleep_time)));

                    if (job.getExecutionTime() >= job.getDuration()) {
                        auto completion_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime);
                        job.setCompletionTime(completion_time.count());
                        std::lock_guard completedLock(c_mutex);
                        completedJobsQueue.push_back(job);
                        std::stringstream msg2;
                        msg2 << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] completed " << job.getId() << " at t = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime).count() << std::endl;
                        std::cout << msg2.str();
                    } else {
                        runningLock.lock();
                        runningJobsQueue.push(job);
                        std::stringstream msg2;
                        msg2 << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] pushed " << job.getId() << " at t = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime).count() << std::endl;
                        std::cout << msg2.str();
                        is_empty.notify_one();
                    }

                } else {
                    runningLock.lock();
                    done = true;
                    is_empty.notify_all();
                }


            }

            std::stringstream msg3;
            msg3 << "[" << std::this_thread::get_id() << "] finished at t = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime).count() << std::endl;
            std::cout << msg3.str();


        });
    }

    while (!waitingJobsQueue.empty()) {

        Job job = waitingJobsQueue.top();
        float start_time = std::chrono::milliseconds(job.getStartTime()).count();
        std::stringstream msg;
        msg << "[JobScheduler] sleeping " << start_time << " ms to start job " << job.getId() << std::endl;
        std::cout << msg.str();


        auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime);


        if (elapsed_time.count() < job.getStartTime()) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(job.getStartTime()-elapsed_time.count()));
        }


        {
            std::lock_guard lockGuard(r_mutex);
            waitingJobsQueue.pop();
            runningJobsQueue.push(job);
            std::stringstream msg;
            msg << "[JobScheduler] job " << job.getId() << " pushed into the running queue" << std::endl;
            std::cout << msg.str();
            is_empty.notify_all();
        }

    }
}

JobScheduler::~JobScheduler() {
    for (int i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++) {
        if (threadPool[i].joinable()) {
            threadPool[i].join();
        }
    }

    float completed_queue_size = completedJobsQueue.size();
    float max_compl_time = 0;
    float tot_exec_time = 0;
    float tot_turnaround_time = 0;
    float tot_waiting_time = 0;
    for (auto &j: completedJobsQueue) {
        j = completedJobsQueue.back();
        completedJobsQueue.pop_back();
        max_compl_time = std::max(static_cast<float>(j.getCompletionTime()), max_compl_time);
        tot_exec_time += j.getExecutionTime();
        tot_waiting_time += j.getWaitTime();
        tot_turnaround_time += j.getCompletionTime() - j.getStartTime();
    }

    float avg_turnaround_time = (tot_turnaround_time/completed_queue_size)/1000;
    float avg_waiting_time = (tot_waiting_time/completed_queue_size)/1000;
    float exec_time = tot_exec_time/(1000*completed_queue_size);
    float compl_time = max_compl_time/1000;
    float cpu_usage = (exec_time/compl_time)*100;

    std::cout.precision(3);
    std::cout << "avg turnaround time " << avg_turnaround_time << "s" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "avg waiting time " << avg_waiting_time << "s" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "exec time " << exec_time << "s" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "compl time " << compl_time << "s" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cpu usage " << cpu_usage << "%" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    JobScheduler p{};
    p.submit(Job(1, 0, 15000));
    p.submit(Job(2, 0, 6000));
    p.submit(Job(3, 1000, 9000));
    p.submit(Job(4, 2000, 12000));
    p.submit(Job(5, 3000, 16000));
    p.submit(Job(6, 3000, 5000));
    p.submit(Job(7, 4000, 7000));
    p.submit(Job(8, 4000, 6000));
    p.submit(Job(9, 5000, 9000));

    p.start();
}
```

UPDATE: I can't reduce the above code. Here is my full output

```
thread 4 created
thread 3 created
thread 2 created
[JobScheduler] sleeping 0 ms to start job 1
[JobScheduler] job 1 pushed into the running queue
thread 5 created
[JobScheduler] sleeping 0 ms to start job 2
[JobScheduler] job 2 pushed into the running queue
[2] running job 1 at t = 1
[JobScheduler] sleeping 1000 ms to start job 3
[5] running job 2 at t = 2
[JobScheduler] job 3 pushed into the running queue
[JobScheduler] sleeping 2000 ms to start job 4
[4] running job 3 at t = 1000
[JobScheduler] job 4 pushed into the running queue
[3] running job 4 at t = 2001
[JobScheduler] sleeping 3000 ms to start job 6
[JobScheduler] job 6 pushed into the running queue
[JobScheduler] sleeping 3000 ms to start job 5
[JobScheduler] job 5 pushed into the running queue
[JobScheduler] sleeping 4000 ms to start job 8
[2] pushed 1 at t = 3003
[2] running job 6 at t = 3003
[5] pushed 2 at t = 3004
[5] running job 5 at t = 3004
[JobScheduler] job 8 pushed into the running queue
[JobScheduler] sleeping 4000 ms to start job 7
[JobScheduler] job 7 pushed into the running queue
[JobScheduler] sleeping 5000 ms to start job 9
[4] pushed 3 at t = 4001
[4] running job 1 at t = 4001
[JobScheduler] job 9 pushed into the running queue
[3] pushed 4 at t = 5002
[3] running job 2 at t = 5002
[2] pushed 6 at t = 6004
[2] running job 8 at t = 6004
[5] pushed 5 at t = 6005
[5] running job 7 at t = 6005
[4] pushed 1 at t = 7002
[4] running job 3 at t = 7002
[3] completed 2 at t = 8002
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted
[5] pushed 7 at t = 9366
[5] running job 4 at t = 9366
[2] pushed 8 at t = 9366
[2] running job 6 at t = 9366

Process finished with exit code 3
```

Comment: Anyway you can pare this down some?

Comment: Boiling your code down to a [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: I can't, if you simply copy-paste this should work with no problem

Answer (score 3):

From looking at the code, not testing it, I can point to the following bug in the logic:

You are calling `runningLock.unlock()` within the loop `while (!done)` and under the condition `if (!runningJobsQueue.empty())`, but `done` will only be set to `true` in the `else` case of that latter condition. So I think you're trying to unlock the same mutex multiple times, which causes the error:

> If there is no associated mutex or the mutex is not locked, `std::system_error` with an error code of `std::errc::operation_not_permitted`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unlock

Comment: Isn't the `runningLock` acquired after the `is_empty.wait`?

Comment: Actually `runningLock` is locked before the `wait`, [released by that, then reacquired](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait). This means your additional `runningLock.lock()` in the `else` branch is unnecessary and wrong, too. But what does this have to do with my answer?

Comment: Because I'm not getting why that mutex is getting unlocked multiple times

Comment: Because, as I assume, under certain conditions (multiple jobs in the queue, or new ones enqueued while the current ones are handled?) the loop, and that line, is executed more than once. Why are you explicitly unlocking anyhow? This would be done when the [`unique_lock` goes out of scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/~unique_lock); that's the main reason you use that helper class at all.